# Extend CodeIgniter Base Model causes Fatal error: Class 'MY_Model' not found

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to extend `CI_Model`:

```
<?php

class ModelBasic extends CI_Model
{

} 

 ?>
```

It won't be autoloaded unless under such a path:

```
./application/core/MY_Model.php
```

It seems name of `MY_Model.php` is mandatory. Now my problem is that when I create `MY_Model.php` CodeIgniter Expects me to have a model under name of `MY_Model` which I want to avoid. Can I have my own custom model name without making a fake class to suppress this error?

```
Fatal error: Class 'MY_Model' not found in /var/www/CodeIgniter/system/core/Common.php on line 174
```

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to achieve naming your own custom base model(s) without any additional modification is to create the file `application/core/MY_Model.php`, define an empty `MY_Model` class, and then create your own custom class(es):

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {}

class ModelBasic extends MY_Model {

    // Your code here
}

// Define more than one if you want.

class ModelComplicated extends MY_Model {

    // Your code here
}
```

Other options include:

1. Extend the Loader class, and replace the `model()` method with your own modified version. This could be complicated (I haven't explored it fully), since the actual error is occurring in `system/core/Common.php` :: `load_class()`, which, in the model's example, is instantiating the base CI_Model class, as well as MY_Model if it finds one (which it automatically looks for by default, like other base classes).
2. Create / Add an autoloader that follows your own rules for loading core classes (may be complicated if you try to autoload more than just models -- really depends on how you want to set your app up).

Answer (score -2):

Extend the Loader class and re-write that part of the code.